# How to reduce memory consumption of Skype?

Tags: windows-xp, performance, skype

I only use Skype for text and audio sometimes. It takes approximately 15 MB of memory. Can I reduce this with any settings or optimizations?

Comment: **Please review the FAQ**. As previously been asked, please spend more time on your questions. Also focus on asking questions that add value to the site and other users.

Comment: @Diago - What wrong with this question

Answer (score 4):

First off, 15MB of RAM is *not a lot of ram*.

Taking a look through the options it doesn't look like there is anything that can be done to lessen the footprint.

Comment: +1 for the "not a lot of RAM". I wish all programs would only use 15 MB RAM. And Skype is not a small program, with all the audio and video processing.